# SVN to passworded network drive

Tags: windows, svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I am trying to access my QNAP File Server for the use of storing SVN files locally on my network. The folder I want to store them in is passworded.
SVN Repository Location:

```
\\NAS1\ryan\SVN\MSVS12
```

The directory "ryan" is password protected. If I access this directly from windows I receive the error:

```
Windows cannot access \\NAS1\ryan\SVN\MSVS12
```

Though if I access "\\NAS1\ryan" directly add in my credentials then both tortoiseSVN and windows has access to it for that session.

I've tried using:

```
file://path;username=user;password=pass
```

and the documentation cannot seem to shed light on my situation either. Would it be easier/better to use a startup script that automatically logs into this folder @login? Or is there another method that might work better?

**EDIT: I decided to use the "net use" command such that in a script file:**

```
net use \\nas1\ryan /user:username password
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. This is a completely unsupported and highly discouraged configuration.

Serving a repository from a UNC share via the `file:///` method may lead to repository loss or corruption (because it's trivial for a user to delete a repository database file with no way to recover), makes any [hook scripts shaky at best (because the execute on the committer's PC, not in a controlled server environment), and affords you zero security within the repository itself (path-based authorization doesn't exist with this access method)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.recommendations) (see the last bullet point on the page). There are also permissions-related bugs that have been discovered in older versions of Samba (which your QNAP may be using) via Subversion that can mess you up as well (see [this note](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#samba)).

Instead, install [Subversion on the QNAP itself](http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Subversion) and access the repository properly via HTTP or svnserve. Side-effect: it completely avoids your passworded UNC share issue.

Comment: Any reference? This is not true at all: *Storing a repository on a UNC share may lead to repository loss or corruption, makes any hook scripts shaky at best, and affords you zero security within the repository itself.*

Comment: It is true. I've added a link to the manual where this practice is discouraged and why.

Comment: storing repositories on a network share and exposing them via Apache HTTP Server is pretty common and valid configuration. I suggest making a not about that because your answer looks like "don't store your repos on a network share in any case".

Comment: Aloc is correct. Sharing `file://` for multiple users is not supported. And, there is absolutely no reason to do this, especially since setting up `svnserve` is so simple to do. Apache httpd can be difficult, but `svnserve` is pretty simple. See the bottom of [this webpage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.htmlO for why this is not far from a good idea.

Comment: Yea, once I get admin access to the Qnap off my mate I'll do an install then. It is only on a home network with all blocked ports on the router for external access...but still!

Answer (score 0):

As Aloc already pointed out, you should never share a repository over `file://`. The Subversion manual is [very firmly against this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html)<sup>1</sup>.

There are multiple reasons: You give users direct access to the repository files which means they can directly manipulate them. There are problems with hooks working correctly. And, there is almost no protection against two people making simultaneous changes in the repository since the svn client itself is directly manipulating the server layout. Bad bad idea.

This is especially true since setting up `svnserve` is so simple to setup. You can even setup `svnserve` as a [Windows Service](http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm). The only possible issue is that your router or firewall block port 3620 (Subversion svnserve's default port).

Here's how to setup `svnserve`:

1. Create a repository (you already have one).
2. Edit the `$REPO_HOME/conf/svnserve.conf` file. You want to change around line #20 to set `password-db = passwd` (or whatever your password database is).
3. Edit the `passwd` file to setup accounts. It's basically `account_name = password`. The file has a comment showing you how to do it.
4. Run `svnserve` manually or as a Windows service.

And, that's pretty much it. It takes about 10 minutes of work.

If you really want to get fancy, you can use Apache httpd. However, that involves installing and configuring Apache httpd which can be a bit difficult on a Windows system - especially if you're not familiar with Apache setup. However, there are [step-by-step directions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) and they're not too difficult to follow. The advantage is that this runs over Port 80 which is less likely to be blocked than port 3620, and you can use your Windows Active Directory for [Subversion authentication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_authz_svn.conf.html)<sup>2</sup>.

However, there are several Windows based Subversion servers such as [http://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/] that make Apache setup much easier, but to get LDAP access, you have to pay for the *Pro* package. You can also look at [CollabNet's package](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion). This is free, but it's a much more *roll your own* solution.

---

<sup>1.</sup> See the very last paragraph on that webpage.
<sup>2.</sup> It is possible to use `svnserve` with LDAP/Windows Active Directory configuration via [SASL](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.overview.html#svn.serverconfig.overview.tbl-1), but I've never seen it used. Probably because those who want to use LDAP/Windows Active Directory already know how to configure everything through Apache httpd.